# Behaviour of margin of h1 tag

Tags: html, css

I have index.html which looks like follows:-

```css
    html {
        background-color: #0000FF;
    }
    body{
        background-color: #FF0000;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My test page</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Mozilla is cool</h1>
        <img src="images/firefox-icon.png" alt="The Firefox logo: a flaming fox surrounding the Earth.">
        <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
        <p>At Mozilla, we’re a global community of</p>
    
        <ul> <!-- changed to list in the tutorial -->
          <li>technologists</li>
          <li>thinkers</li>
          <li>builders</li>
        </ul>
    
        <p>working together to keep the Internet alive and accessible, so people worldwide can be informed contributors and creators of the Web. We believe this act of human collaboration across an open platform is essential to individual growth and our collective future.</p>
    
        <p>Read the <!--a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/manifesto/"--><span>Mozilla Manifesto</span><!--/a--> to learn even more about the values and principles that guide the pursuit of our mission.</p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Initially the margin of h1 is with the window and there is some extra space above body element. But if i add border: 1px solid black to my body element the margin of h1 is with body element.

Why is this so? The border of body element was present even before but we were not just displaying it right?

Comment: Google `collapsing margins`.

Comment: That is normal behaviour for `H1` or any `H` tag markup. You should read up on HTML/CSS 101 courses.

Comment: Also I see the `height` value of the body vary when setting the border..

Comment: why there is no margin collapse when we draw a border across body?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers have a default user agent stylesheet which automatically adds some styles - even if you haven't specified any.

For example, in chrome, i can see that the h1 will be given a slight margin-before and margin-end which would give you the gap between the body and H1.

You can override this default style-sheet by using one of many reset style-sheets [example here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

User agent stylesheets will be overridden by any other styles in the following order:

- Browser/user default
- External
- Internal (inside the  tag)
- Inline (inside an HTML
  element)

It may also be worth reading up on [css specificity](http://csarven.ca/css-specificity-and-selectors) as it explains a lot of simple problems you may come across

Comment: my doubt is not with the user agent stylesheets. Here for the above code if you add border: 1px solid black to body tag the background color of body moves up. But h1 is child of body element. So it should have its margin with respect to body tag right?